# Showing error message from Project server 2010 wcf service

Tags: wcf, ms-project-server-2010

I implemented a web application that connects to a ProjectServer.svc web service. The application works on a project environment server, but returns an error in the production server. Unluckly, due to security settings the text and code  of the exception taking place on the server is not shown, instead I get this message:

*The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs*

I modified the wcf settings in the web config of project server to make the web service return the error...but nothing happened, because probably Project server overrides the web config wcf settings.

How can I get the error message, so I can understand what is wrong with the server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ULS log may help - when Project server process accepted your call and error somewhere inside of the process.

I touched the configs only once to create Proxy assembly and that time it worked... maybe the same approach will help you to find proper config. Here is a link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff621594(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff621594%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Don't forget `iisreset` after you change the config

Comment: Hi  thanks for the answer. Nothing relevant found in the ULS. Probably because ProjectServer.svc returned the error befor passing the request to Project Server...This restrict the possible errors to security, network or WCF settings related issues I imagine...but without the error text...it is difficult to imagine what...the problem is...I will read the link you provided ...and if I find something feasible...I will instruct my customer to try it...and then I will return to you. Thanks again